# Replace anchor tag with more parameters

Tags: java, anchor

Can any one give me the java logic for replacing all the anchor tags with more options. Example `this is the paragraph where the <a href="firstlink" >firstlink </a> and here goes <a href="secondlink" >secondlink </a> and so on...`
And output should be

```
this is the paragraph where the <a href="firstlink" target="_blank" >firstlink </a> and here goes <a href="secondlink" target="_blank" >secondlink </a> and so on...
```

I have tried it with the below core java code,  which gave me only first occurred anchor tag added with `target="_blank"`.

```
public class StringMod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter string:");
        String input=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("input given as:"+input);
        System.out.println("Enter data to append:");
        int start=input.indexOf("<a");
        int last=input.indexOf("\">");
        input=input.substring(start, last+2);
        String input2=sc.nextLine();
        String result=getModified(input,input2);
        System.out.println("Fianlly op:"+result);
    }

    private static String getModified(String input, String input2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i=input.indexOf(">");
        String begin=input.substring(0, i);
        String middle=input2;
        middle=" "+middle;
        String result=begin+middle+">";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you show what you have tried first. Please update your question.

Comment: You'll probably get better results if you use an XML or HTML parser than trying to do this with strings and regex.  It only *seems* like it should be harder.